# remove the 0's in count down timer

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I have created a countdown timer that counts down from 10:00, I want the countdown timer to remove the first 0 once it gets below 1 minute. and include the ending zero once its below 10 seconds.

For Example: "0:59" I want to remove the 0 so it should show ":59" and then ":9" should show ":09"

To be 100 percent honest, I have not tried much.. I thought that maybe this could be done with a regular expression, but I am unsure how.

My Timer:

```
const mins = 10;
// getting the exact time as of the page load
const now = new Date().getTime();
// the math that is done for the actual countdown. So 10*60*1000 + the time retrieved from the page load.
const deadline = mins * 60 * 1000 + now;

// This is a function, however it is a JavaScript method and calls a function.
setInterval(() => {
  // Gets the current time
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  //   gets the 'distance' between the deadline(10 mins) and the current time
  var distance = deadline - currentTime;
  //   found out this method does the math for you, I had to look this up and research it on W3schools
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  // Inserts the timer into the Span timer
  timeSpan.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds;
  //   the interval is set to 1 sec, so the timer refreshes and counts down every second

  if (seconds < 0) {
    confirm('Alert For your User!');
    window.location.reload();
  }
}, 1000);
```

I haven't added anything in the way of starting, because I am unsure where to start! any help would be great.

Comment: Compared to 0:59, :59 reads poorly in my opinion. Perhaps just don't remove the 0's and move on?

Comment: I'm a little confused. `.9 ` isn't `.09` - not sure what you mean?

Comment: @zfrisch - When it goes from 10 seconds to 9 seconds, as in :10 :9, he wants it to read :10 :09.

Comment: @TravisJ its for an assignment, I agree 100% to you however, that how the instructor wants it. as for the seconds I want it to read :09, :08... ect..  it says to prepend the 0..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

You can use simple `if` statements to alter the output right before it goes to the screen.

```
  // check if seconds is single digit
  if(seconds.toString().length === 1) { seconds = "0" + seconds }
  // check if minutes is zero ( which is falsy )
  if(!minutes) minutes = "";
  // Inserts the timer into the Span timer
  timeSpan.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds;
```

---

You also can declare a variable to hold a reference to the `interval`

```
// declare the interval as a variable so you can clear it!
let my_interval = setInterval(() => {
```

This allows you to clear it when it is no longer needed to run:

```
if (seconds < 0) {
    confirm('Alert For your User!');
    //clear the interval when it finishes!
    clearInterval(my_interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

---

### Code Snippet:

```js
let timeSpan = document.querySelector("#timeSpan");
const mins = 1;
// getting the exact time as of the page load
const now = new Date().getTime();
// the math that is done for the actual countdown. So 10*60*1000 + the time retrieved from the page load.
const deadline = mins * 60 * 1000 + now;

// This is a function, however it is a JavaScript method and calls a function.

// declare the interval as a variable so you can clear it!
let my_interval = setInterval(() => {
  // Gets the current time
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  //   gets the 'distance' between the deadline(10 mins) and the current time
  var distance = deadline - currentTime;
  //   found out this method does the math for you, I had to look this up and research it on W3schools
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
  // check if seconds is single digit
  if(seconds.toString().length === 1) { seconds = "0" + seconds }
  // check if minutes is zero ( which is falsy )
  if(!minutes) minutes = "";
  // Inserts the timer into the Span timer
  timeSpan.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds;
  
  //   the interval is set to 1 sec, so the timer refreshes and counts down every second

  if (seconds < 0) {
    confirm('Alert For your User!');
    //clear the interval when it finishes!
    clearInterval(my_interval);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I appreciate more help! and I appreciate the help with the last part also!

Comment: @ShaunStone This is a better way of doing it IMO. | Please upvote both posts if you found them helpful (click the up arrow next to the answers).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some basic if statements (see below), but as people in the comments have said, it looks odd to have it read `:59` instead of `0:59`

```js
const timeSpan = document.querySelector('#test');
const mins = 10;
// getting the exact time as of the page load
const now = new Date().getTime();
// the math that is done for the actual countdown. So 10*60*1000 + the time retrieved from the page load.
const deadline = 62 * 1000 + now;

// This is a function, however it is a JavaScript method and calls a function.
setInterval(() => {
  // Gets the current time
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  //   gets the 'distance' between the deadline(10 mins) and the current time
  var distance = deadline - currentTime;
  //   found out this method does the math for you, I had to look this up and research it on W3schools
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  if (minutes > 0) {
     if(seconds < 10){
            timeSpan.innerHTML = minutes + ':0' + seconds;
      } else {
             // Inserts the timer into the Span timer
             timeSpan.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds;
       }
 
  } else if(seconds < 10) {
   timeSpan.innerHTML = ':0' + seconds;
  } else {
    timeSpan.innerHTML = ':' + seconds;
  }

  //   the interval is set to 1 sec, so the timer refreshes and counts down every second

  if (seconds < 0) {
    confirm('Alert For your User!');
    window.location.reload();
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="test">
</p>
```

Comment: wow.. such and easy way of doing it!! haha! if I had to prepend it, how would I do it? I know that it deals with the `format()` method

Comment: @ShaunStone What do you mean by "prepend it"? | also, if this solve your issue please mark it as accepted and upvote.

Comment: done :) and my JavaScript experience is poor. I will just use your answer. and I apprecaite the help!

Comment: @ShaunStone Just a heads up, my solution isn't great code practices. Its more of a quick way to get what you want done. There are better ways of doing what you are asking, including creating a separate formatting function.